# Change Model/Controller for specific template in emberJS

Tags: ember.js, model, routes

I'm new on emberJS. I'm trying to get my head straight to understand, 
Route-Template-Controller-View-Model.

Here's my code:
// app.js

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
    return App.FIXTURES; // some data for the index route
 },
 setupController: function(controller, model) {
     var self = this;
     // sets the model for the current route
     controller.set('model', model);

     // render the dashboard template,
     // Problem: I want the model of this template 'dashboard' to be changed, 
     // how can I achieved that?
     self.render('dashboard', {
        // Is this correct here? I pass an anonymous function to change the controller? 
        // I got an error for doing so
        controller: function() {
           console.log(this);
        }
     });
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to call render, ember handles all that for you. If you have a template named "index" it will render that automatically, or you can set the template on your IndexView.

If you want to change the model, instead of `controller.set('model', model);` don't use the passed model, find one using `this.store` http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/
and set that model on the controller.

Comment: Hi, the `self.render('dashboard')` there is another template to be rendered. As I want that template's model set for another, is it possible? or my approach is wrong?

Comment: @meetmahpuppy if you want to load a template within the view's template you can use the `{{render}}` helper to load it with a specified model http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/